# How to create a new copy of a theme currently being used?

Tags: themes

I want to copy the theme I am using now, so that I can change it an test online (using the Theme Test Drive plugin). At this moment I haven't ftp, telnet or even access to the database.

Is there any way I can re-install the theme I am using under another name? So that I could change that?

Comment: That sounds like a very lamentable situation.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you do have full access to admin?

Several options I came up with without much thinking:

1. Make an archive with modified copy of theme, install it through file upload. Obviously this is easier if you have copy of theme, otherwise you might have to build it file by file from sources accessible in theme `Editor`.
2. Create child theme for original theme, install via file upload. Might or might not fit, depending on what you want to do.
3. Create a plugin that will on activation copy theme to another folder and modify its detail. Little bit too geeky.

Comment: #2. If you have to modify a theme's code (function.php), you're better off making a child. That will allow you to receive updates to the theme core without having to worry about losing your changes.

Answer (score 0):

Download it from the themes directory?